# I do not get a logout option on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, login

I use Firefox ESR 24.2. I log in to Stack Overflow using the Yahoo login. Previously, I used to get a logout option after logging in. Nowadays I do not get a logout option. What should I do? Is it normal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on the Stack Exchange image on the top-left. You will see ***log out*** next to Stack Overflow:

[image]

Comment: Earlier it used to come to some other place. Thanks